# Are the words for one and for going cognates in PIE?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, numerals

We have in PIE:

***e̯eitr*** way, pedestrian road

***e̯imos*** road

***e̯iera̯*** year

***e̯eiti*** goes

***e̯iteros*** other, another, next

I wonder whether the word for "one"

***e̯oinos*** alone, separated

connected to the above?

Note that the PIE word ***e̯oinos*** had clear meaning of "one alone", "one separated" contrasted with another word for "one", ***som*** which meant "united", "one together".

There was also word for "thus", "ergo", "it follows that" which confusingly Mallory gives as ***e̯ita̯*** while Beekes gives as ***e̯ei*** and analyses as locative case of pronoun ***e̯e*** "that".

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as we know to this moment it is not.

The word "один" is related to [this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Indo-European/%C3%B3ynos#Proto-Indo-European) PIE root (*h₁ey), and the word "идти" - to [this one](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%81ey-#Proto-Indo-European), which also is transliterated like (*h₁ey), but this is a coincidence. Personally I never've heard such assumption.